# Setting up LDAP connection between CentOS and Windows server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, ldap, centos6.2

I am running a virtual setup with vSphere, with two virtual machines, one running CentOS 6 and the other running Windows server 2008

The idea is to use LDAP to connect from the CentOS (as a client) to the Windows Server 2008 (as a server), and trying to access Active Directory from there.

There is a virtual switch between these two virtual machines, and both are running on the same subnet.

On CentOS, I try to run the LDAP to connect to the Win 2008 server with:

```
ldapsearch -x
```

The error message I get is:

> text: 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906DC, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0

Meanwhile, I opened the Event Viewer on Windows server, and the error message that I get is:

> The directory server has failed to create the AD LDS ServiceConnectionPoint object in Active Directory Lightweight Directory services. This operation will be retried.

Now I'm not exactly sure what the problem is, am I supposed to specify an admin login in the CentOS .conf file? If so, which one?

Or is this a Windows server permission issue?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is fairly straightforward:

```
text: 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906DC, comment: In order to perform this 
operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0
```

That means you need to authenticate before you can query the directory.  A typical command line will look something like this:

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://dc.example.com/ -D lars@example.com -W cn=lars
```

This connect using simple authentication (`-x`) to `dc.example.com` using LDAP over SSL (`ldaps://`).  I am authenticating as `lars@example.com` and the command will prompt me for a password (`-W`).  I am searching for records matching `cn=lars`.

You can also authenticate against AD using Kerberos.  Assuming everything is set up correctly, that looks like:

```
$ kinit lars@example.com
Password for lars@EXAMPLE>COM: 
$ ldapsearch -H ldap://dc.example.com cn=lars
```

In either case, you generally want to create accounts specifically to act as bind credentials, rather than using an administrative or a user account.

It is [possible](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/appnote/15120.html) to configure Active Directory to allow anonymous binds. It is also possible to set up something else -- e.g., [OpenLDAP](http://openldap.org/) -- as an anonymous bind proxy for AD.

Comment: Hi Larsks, thanks for your answer. I have successfully pinged my server using the ldapsearch and retrieved information from it. However, I am trying to set it up so that when I type `getent passwd`, I would like the retrieve the list of Users in the database. However, that doesn't seem to work. I was following this link: http://beginlinux.com/server_training/server-managment-topics/1316-set-up-ldap-client . Am I missing something from that tutorial? Please let me know if you would like me to post more info. Thanks!!